# Get a List of Child Processes from Parent Process in C and C++ (Cross-Platform, No Command Line)

Tags: c, cross-platform, desktop, pid

How to get a list of child process ID's from a given parent process ID in a cross-platform manner in C and C++ without using command line? I provided an answer myself below which covers Win32, macOS, Linux, FreeBSD, DragonFly BSD, OpenBSD, NetBSD, and Darwin, in C++.

Feel free to convert my code to a C solution, (along with native API's or POSIX as needed), or provide your own solutions using a different API or approach, but without using stuff like popen() or system(). Adding support for more platforms is obviously also welcome.

For example: Illumos variants, mobile platforms, etc.

Comment: Did you consider using [Qt](https://qt.io) or [POCO](https://pcoproject.org/) ?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch For Qt the GPL/LGPL is a huge turn off to some, I come from a background of preferring permissive licenses and not having to pay for it. I've never heard of POCO but the page you linked isn't loading for me currently, I'll check it out as soon as my internet connection allows it.

Comment: Sorry, https://pocoproject.org/

Comment: Yeah, appears to also have pro version which isn't free. Thanks for sharing though, the boost licensing looks promising on the free version, and not everyone is as picky as I am. I prefer doing as much in-house as I can.

Answer (score 9):

The code below was mostly pulled from [this command line app I wrote](https://github.com/time-killer-games/xproc).

Win32

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

#include "childpids.h"

#include <windows.h>
#include <tlhelp32.h>

using std::vector;

void ProcIdFromParentProcId(PROCID parentProcId, PROCID **procId, int *size) {
  vector<PROCID> vec; int i = 0;
  HANDLE hp = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, 0);
  PROCESSENTRY32 pe = { 0 };
  pe.dwSize = sizeof(PROCESSENTRY32);
  if (Process32First(hp, &pe)) {
    do {
      if (pe.th32ParentProcessID == parentProcId) {
        vec.push_back(pe.th32ProcessID); i++;
      }
    } while (Process32Next(hp, &pe));
  }
  CloseHandle(hp);
  *procId = (PROCID *)malloc(sizeof(PROCID) * vec.size());
  if (procId) {
    std::copy(vec.begin(), vec.end(), *procId);
    *size = i;
  }
}
```

macOS & Darwin

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

#include "childpids.h"

#include <sys/proc_info.h>
#include <libproc.h>

using std::vector;

void ParentProcIdFromProcId(PROCID procId, PROCID *parentProcId) {
  proc_bsdinfo proc_info;
  if (proc_pidinfo(procId, PROC_PIDTBSDINFO, 0, &proc_info, sizeof(proc_info)) > 0) {
    *parentProcId = proc_info.pbi_ppid;
  }
}

void ProcIdFromParentProcId(PROCID parentProcId, PROCID **procId, int *size) {
  vector<PROCID> vec; int i = 0;
  int cntp = proc_listpids(PROC_ALL_PIDS, 0, nullptr, 0);
  vector<PROCID> proc_info(cntp);
  std::fill(proc_info.begin(), proc_info.end(), 0);
  proc_listpids(PROC_ALL_PIDS, 0, &proc_info[0], sizeof(PROCID) * cntp);
  // this Darwin API ^ lists them in reverse order from other platforms
  for (int j = cntp - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
    if (proc_info[j] == 0) { continue; }
    PROCID ppid; ParentProcIdFromProcId(proc_info[j], &ppid);
    if (proc_info[j] > 0 && ppid >= 0 && ppid == parentProcId) {
      vec.push_back(proc_info[j]); i++;
    }
  }
  *procId = (PROCID *)malloc(sizeof(PROCID) * vec.size());
  if (procId) {
    std::copy(vec.begin(), vec.end(), *procId);
    *size = i;
  }
}
```

Linux (link with: -lprocps)

```
// Note: Ubuntu/Debian need to install libprocps-dev for the development headers.
// All major Linux distros *should* have the actual library installed by default.
// Arch-Linux/Gentoo are exceptions if users did not install a DE which needs it.

#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

#include "childpids.h"

#include <proc/readproc.h>

using std::vector;

void ProcIdFromParentProcId(PROCID parentProcId, PROCID **procId, int *size) {
  vector<PROCID> vec; int i = 0;
  PROCTAB *proc = openproc(PROC_FILLSTAT);
  while (proc_t *proc_info = readproc(proc, nullptr)) {
    if (proc_info->ppid == parentProcId) {
      vec.push_back(proc_info->tgid); i++;
    }
    freeproc(proc_info);
  }
  *procId = (PROCID *)malloc(sizeof(PROCID) * vec.size());
  if (procId) {
    std::copy(vec.begin(), vec.end(), *procId);
    *size = i;
  }
}
```

FreeBSD (link with: -lutil -lc)

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

#include <cstdlib>

#include "childpids.h"

#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/user.h>

#include <libutil.h>

using std::vector;

void ProcIdFromParentProcId(PROCID parentProcId, PROCID **procId, int *size) {
  vector<PROCID> vec; int i = 0; int cntp;
  if (kinfo_proc *proc_info = kinfo_getallproc(&cntp)) {
    for (int j = 0; j < cntp; j++) {
      if (proc_info[j].ki_ppid == parentProcId) {
        vec.push_back(proc_info[j].ki_pid); i++;
      }
    }
    free(proc_info);
  }
  *procId = (PROCID *)malloc(sizeof(PROCID) * vec.size());
  if (procId) {
    std::copy(vec.begin(), vec.end(), *procId);
    *size = i;
  }
}
```

DragonFly BSD  (link with: -lkvm -lc)

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

#include <cstdlib>
#include <climits>

#include "childpids.h"

#include <fcntl.h>

#include <sys/param.h>
#include <sys/sysctl.h>
#include <sys/user.h>

#include <kvm.h>

using std::vector;

void ProcIdFromParentProcId(PROCID parentProcId, PROCID **procId, int *size) {
  vector<PROCID> vec; int i = 0;
  char errbuf[_POSIX2_LINE_MAX];
  static kvm_t *kd = nullptr; kinfo_proc *proc_info = nullptr;
  const char *nlistf, *memf; nlistf = memf = "/dev/null";
  kd = kvm_openfiles(nlistf, memf, nullptr, O_RDONLY, errbuf); if (!kd) return;
  int cntp = 0; if ((proc_info = kvm_getprocs(kd, KERN_PROC_ALL, 0, &cntp))) {
    for (int j = 0; j < cntp; j++) {
      if (proc_info[j].kp_pid > 0 && proc_info[j].kp_ppid >= 0 && 
        proc_info[j].kp_ppid == parentProcId) {
        vec.push_back(proc_info[j].kp_pid); i++;
      }
    }
  }
  kvm_close(kd);
  *procId = (PROCID *)malloc(sizeof(PROCID) * vec.size());
  if (procId) {
    std::copy(vec.begin(), vec.end(), *procId);
    *size = i;
  }
}
```

OpenBSD  (link with: -lkvm -lc)

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

#include <cstdlib>
#include <climits>

#include "childpids.h"

#include <sys/param.h>
#include <sys/sysctl.h>
#include <sys/user.h>

#include <kvm.h>

using std::vector;

void ProcIdFromParentProcId(PROCID parentProcId, PROCID **procId, int *size) {
  vector<PROCID> vec; int i = 0;
  char errbuf[_POSIX2_LINE_MAX]; int cntp = 0;
  static kvm_t *kd = nullptr; kinfo_proc *proc_info = nullptr; 
  kd = kvm_openfiles(nullptr, nullptr, nullptr, KVM_NO_FILES, errbuf); if (!kd) return;
  if ((proc_info = kvm_getprocs(kd, KERN_PROC_ALL, 0, sizeof(struct kinfo_proc), &cntp))) {
    // this API ^ on OpenBSD lists the them in reverse order like Darwin
    for (int j = cntp - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
      if (proc_info[j].p_pid > 0 && proc_info[j].p_ppid >= 0 &&
        proc_info[j].p_ppid == parentProcId) {
        vec.push_back(proc_info[j].p_pid); i++;
      }
    }
  }
  kvm_close(kd);
  *procId = (PROCID *)malloc(sizeof(PROCID) * vec.size());
  if (procId) {
    std::copy(vec.begin(), vec.end(), *procId);
    *size = i;
  }
}
```

NetBSD (link with: -lkvm -lc)

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

#include <cstdlib>
#include <climits>

#include "childpids.h"

#include <sys/param.h>
#include <sys/sysctl.h>

#include <kvm.h>

using std::vector;

void ProcIdFromParentProcId(PROCID parentProcId, PROCID **procId, int *size) {
  vector<PROCID> vec; int i = 0;
  char errbuf[_POSIX2_LINE_MAX]; int cntp = 0;
  static kvm_t *kd = nullptr; kinfo_proc2 *proc_info = nullptr;
  kd = kvm_openfiles(nullptr, nullptr, nullptr, KVM_NO_FILES, errbuf); if (!kd) return;
  if ((proc_info = kvm_getproc2(kd, KERN_PROC_ALL, 0, sizeof(struct kinfo_proc2), &cntp))) {
    // this API ^ on NetBSD lists the them in reverse order like Darwin and OpenBSD
    for (int j = cntp - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
      if (proc_info[j].p_pid > 0 && proc_info[j].p_ppid >= 0 &&
        proc_info[j].p_ppid == parentProcId) {
        vec.push_back(proc_info[j].p_pid); i++;
      }
    }
  }
  kvm_close(kd);
  *procId = (PROCID *)malloc(sizeof(PROCID) * vec.size());
  if (procId) {
    std::copy(vec.begin(), vec.end(), *procId);
    *size = i;
  }
}
```

childpids.h

```
#ifdef _WIN32
typedef unsigned long PROCID;
#else
typedef int PROCID;
#endif

void ProcIdFromParentProcId(PROCID parentProcId, PROCID **procId, int *size);
```

childpids.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

#include <cstring>

#include "childpids.h"

using std::vector;

void PrintPidFromPpidRecursive(PROCID parentProcId) {
  PROCID *procId; int size;
  ProcIdFromParentProcId(parentProcId, &procId, &size);
  if (procId) {
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
      if (procId[i] == 0) { break; }
      PrintPidFromPpidRecursive(procId[i]);
      std::cout << procId[i] << std::endl;
    }
    free(procId);
  }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  PROCID parentProcId = (argc == 2) ? strtoul(argv[1], nullptr, 10) : 0;
  PrintPidFromPpidRecursive(parentProcId);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hard to see the point. The parent process created all these child processes. Why not just have it save them when it created them? This way you are traversing the entire process tree.

Comment: The question does not ask how to get a children process id's from the calling process. It asks how to get children process id's from an arbitrary parent process id. It does not traverse the entire process tree if you pass an existing process id as a command line parameter.

Comment: PrintPidFromPpidRecursive() prints a recursive tree as you mentioned, but not the entire process tree if you plug in anything higher than zero as a command line parameter to the executable, ProcIdFromParentProcId() is not recursive and can stand on its own as the answer. However some people might find recursion useful, thus i used that as additional reasoning for how this could be useful. It's hard for me to see your point.

Comment: Interestingly note: though the process swapper has a process id of zero, depending on the operating system, some platforms in the code above include process id zero in their process enumeration functions, while others do not. Which is odd, because using the kill() system call does indicate process id zero is valid on all of the above platforms, save Windows.